# LINQ OrderBy values that are equal sort them by another property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

Object:

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
public bool? Main { get; set; }
```

I have a list of items which I want to sort.

First it will be the items that have the property Main == true, with EndDate null

Then I want to have the items desceding by start date , and if the start date are equal sort them descending by end date

This is my attempt:

```
items.OrderByDescending(p => p.Main == true && p.EndDate == null)
                           .ThenByDescending(p => p.StartDate)
                           .ThenByDescending(p => p.EndDate).ToList();
```

Not actually the result I was expecting, can you have like a condition when ordering, if values are equal than sort after other values?

Comment: Why is that not the result what you expect? Show a sample, the result and what you actually expect.

Comment: Which result do you get and which do you expect? Add some example please.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code in this question and it should give the correct results with the possible exception that the OP does not explicitly specify how he wants nulls to be handled. But I'm voting to close partly because it is unclear what the problem is, but mainly because of the quality of the current answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build to result sets and concat them.

```
var maintrue = items.Where(p => p.Main == true && p.EndDate == null);
var others = items.Where(i => !maintrue.Contains(i))
                  .OrderByDescending(p => p.StartDate)
                  .ThenByDescending(p => p.EndDate);

var result = maintrue.Concat(others).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a bit overkill, but you could use a custom comparer:

```
class ObjComparer
    : IComparer<Obj>
{
    public int Compare(Obj x, Obj y)
    {
        int compare = CompareByProperties(x, y);
        if (compare == 0)
        {
            compare = CompareByDate(x.StartDate, y.StartDate);
            if (compare == 0)
            {
                compare = CompareByDate(x.EndDate, y.EndDate);
            }
        }
        return compare;
    }

    static int CompareByProperties(Obj o1, Obj o2)
    {
        return MainIsTrueAndEndDateIsNull(o1) ?
                (MainIsTrueAndEndDateIsNull(o2) ? 0 : 1) :
                (MainIsTrueAndEndDateIsNull(o2) ? -1 : 0);
    }

    static bool MainIsTrueAndEndDateIsNull(Obj o)
    {
        return o.Main.Value && o.EndDate == null;
    }

    static int CompareByDate(DateTime? d1, DateTime? d2)
    {
        return d1 == d2 ? 0 : (d1 > d2 ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

Simply used as:

```
var orderedItems = items.OrderBy(o => o, new ObjComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the data.  Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;



namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<MyDate> dates = new List<MyDate>() {
                new MyDate() { Main = true, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/3/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = true,                                       EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/4/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = true, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/2/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/5/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = true, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/3/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/6/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = false, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/4/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/7/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = true,                                       EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/8/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = true, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/4/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/9/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = false, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/5/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/10/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = false, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/5/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/11/17") },
                new MyDate() { Main = false, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/5/17"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/12/17") }
            };

            var results = dates.Select(p => new { key = p.Main == true && p.EndDate == null, date = p })
                .GroupBy(x => x.key).Select(y => y.GroupBy(z => z.date.StartDate).Select(a => a.OrderBy(b => b.date.EndDate)))
                    .SelectMany(y => y).SelectMany(x => x).Select(p => p.date).ToList();

            foreach(MyDate result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",
                    result.Main == null ? "" : result.Main == true ? "true" : "false",
                    result.StartDate.ToString(),
                    result.EndDate.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class MyDate
    {
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public bool? Main { get; set; } 
    }
}
```